# running a graphql mutation & query at the same time, via postman, or in general?

Tags: graphql, postman, gql, postman-graphql

I'm trying to extract some metadata reliably from graphql requests from my loggigng module, but to do this I'm trying to test some more advanced scenarios.

I've tried a lot of variations of the following, some of them with the help of chatGPT (which was hilariously useless):

```
mutation signup{
    sign1: signUp  (SignUpInput: {name: "potato"}) {
        id
        email
        phone
        createdAt
    }

        sign2: signUp  (SignUpInput: {name: "potato"}) {
        id
        email
        phone
        createdAt
    }
}

 query health{
    health: userGraphHealth 
}
```

unfortunately I keep getting `Must provide operation name if query contains multiple operations.` error.

Is it not possible/not a pattern at all, to run mutations and queries in the same document/operation?

Or is this simply a postman limitation?

EDIT: I have re-added the postman tag because this is a caveat around how postman works with graphql.

Comment: Postman is just an HTTP client, it doesn't have limitations. Maybe show your query?

Comment: Hi, the query is right there in the post, I have read somewhere that it actually isn't possible to mix a query with a mutation, most clients get around this by sending multiple 'docs' as part of 1 request, but the way postman is built doesn't allow that, which is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by query? A mutation is a query. Every request sent to GraphQL is a query. Postman does allow all kinds of requests, even malformed. It's an HTTP client, just put the things you want to query/request in the appropriate fields.

Comment: Daniel, semantically there's 'query' and 'mutation' in the context I'm referring to, how graphql sees them as 'operations' under the hood is rather irrelevant -- simply try an equivalent of the above in postman, it does not know how construct the request in a valid way, this isn't a problem with clients like apollo, altair graphql for example makes you choose which of the 'operations' you want to send and splits it into 2 requests.

Postman is a lot more than just a 'http' client.